# Energy Method to show uniqueness of solution of PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In my notes there is the following example about the energy method.

$$u_{tt}(x, t)-u_{xxtt}(x, t)-u_{xx}(x, t)=0, 0<x<1, t>0 \\ u(x, 0)=0 \\ u_t(x, 0)=0 \\ u_x(0, t)=0 \\ u_x(1, t)=0$$

$$\int_0^1(u_tu_{tt}-u_tu_{xxtt}-u_tu_{xx})dx=0 \tag 1$$

$$\int_0^1 u_tu_{tt}dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{2}(u_t^2)_tdx=\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}u_t^2dx$$

$$\int_0^1 u_t u_{xxtt}dx=-\int_0^1 u_{tx}u_{xtt}dx+[u_t u_{xtt}]_0^1=-\int_0^1\frac{1}{2}(u_{tx}^2)_tdx$$

$$\int_0^1 u_t u_{xx}dx=-\int_0^1 u_{tx}u_x dx+[u_t u_x]_0^1=-\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \int_0^1 u_x^2dx$$

$$(1) \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}u_t^2dx+\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 u_{tx}^2dx+\frac{d}{dt} \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 u_x^2dx=0$$

The energy of the system is $$E(t)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 (u_t^2(x, t)+u_{tx}^2(x, t)+u_{x}^2(x, t))dx$$

I wanted to apply this at the following :

$$w_{tt}(x, t)-w_{xxt}(x, t)-w_{xx}(x, t)=0, 0<x<1, t>0 \\ w(x, 0)=0 \\ w_t(x, 0)=0 \\ w(0, t)=0 \\ w(1, t)=0$$

$$\int_0^1(w_tw_{tt}-w_tw_{xxt}-w_tw_{xx})dx=0 \tag 1$$

$$\int_0^1 w_tw_{tt}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}\left (\frac{1}{2}w_t^2\right )dx=\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}w_t^2dx$$

$$\int_0^1 w_t w_{xxt}dx=-\int_0^1 w_{tx}\frac{d}{dx}[w_{xt}]dx=[w_t w_{xt}]_0^1-\int_0^1 w_{xt}^2dx=-\int_0^1 w_{xt}^2dx$$

$$\int_0^1 w_t w_{xx}dx=\int_0^1 w_t \frac{d}{dx}[w_x]dx=[w_t w_x]_0^1-\int_0^1 w_{tx}w_xdx=-\int_0^1 w_{tx} w_x dx=-\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt} \left (\frac{1}{2} w_x^2\right )dx=-\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \int_0^1 w_x^2 dx$$

How could we find of the method in this case??

**EDIT1 :**

When we have the problem $$v_{tt}(x, t)-v_{xt}(x, t)=0, x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0 \\ v(x, 0)=0, x \in \mathbb{R} \\ v_t(x, 0)=0, x \in \mathbb{R}$$

which are the limits of the integral?? In this case $x \in \mathbb{R}$, do we have to take the integral on $\mathbb{R}$ ??

**EDIT2 :**

$$v_{tt}-v_{xt}=f $$ The characteristic curves are $$x=x_0 \text{ AND } x+t=x_0+t_0$$

$$\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}(v_tv_{tt}-v_tv_{xt})dx=0$$

- $$\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}v_tv_{tt}dx=\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\left (\frac{1}{2}v_t^2\right )dx=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}\frac{1}{2}v_t^2dx$$
- $$\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}v_tv_{xt}dx=\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}v_t\left [\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}v_t\right ]dx=[v_t^2]_{x=x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}-\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}v_{xt}v_tdx \Rightarrow \int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}v_tv_{xt}dx=\frac{1}{2}\left (v_t^2(x_0+t_0-t, t)-v_t^2(x_0, t)\right )$$

Is this correct so far?? How could we find the energy??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you have an energy *inequality* as opposed to an *identity*.

Plug in the three pieces into (1) and you will get

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^1 \frac12(u_t^2+u_x^2)dx+\int_0^1u_{xt}^2dx=0 $$

so

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^1 \frac12(u_t^2+u_x^2)dx\le0. $$

Let $E(t)$ be the obvious energy, then you get $E(0)=0$ and $E'(0)\le0$, so $E(t)\le0$.
By positivity, however, $E(t)\ge0$, so $E(t)=0$, and you are done.

P.S. Only in rare cases can you get an energy identity. Upon only the slightest perturbation of the problem, this becomes an inequality, which you can use to *bound* $E(t)$ in terms of $E(0)$.

Comment: So, we have $$E(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}(u_t^2+u_x^2)dx$$ How do we get the initial value $E(0)=0$?? It is $$E(0)=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}(u_t^2(x, 0)+u_x^2(x, 0))dx \overset{ u_t(x, 0)=0 }{ = } \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} u_x^2(x, 0)dx$$ How do we get that this is equal to $0$ ?? Is it because $$u(x, 0)=0 \Rightarrow u_x(x, 0)=0$$ ??

Comment: I have edited my initial post... Could you take a look at it?? @FanZheng

Comment: Yes, but did you ask a different problem in your edit?

Comment: Yes, it is an other problem... @FanZheng

Comment: @MaryStar Hint: Let $w=v_t$. Then it's a transport equation.

Comment: By setting $w=v_t$ we get: $$w_t(x, t)-w_x(x, t)=0$$ To get the energy do we not have to take an integral?? But with what limits?? @FanZheng

Comment: @MaryStar I guess in this case the easiest way is to integrate along the characteristics $t=x-x_0$.

Comment: How did you find the characteristics?? @FanZheng

Comment: Do we not need the value of $w_t$ at the characteristics?? @FanZheng

Comment: @MaryStar  If you have a PDE $aw_t+bw_x=c$, then the characteristics is solved from the ODE $dt/ds=a$ and $dx/ds=b$. Integrating along it gives $dw/ds=c$, so you only need the initial value of $w$, not $w_t$

Comment: I tried to find the energy without setting $w=v_t$, but I got stuck... Could you take a look at my initial post, which I have edited, and tel me how we could continue?? @FanZheng

Comment: Or is the way I tried to find the energy wrong?? @FanZheng